# Copying an entire row based on cell value and pasting in new worksheet, stopping on blank cell

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying to figure out how to copy an entire row and paste it into a specific worksheet based on the value in one particular cell within that row. I've pieced together a couple different codes to do what I need except that I need it to end once it reaches a blank cell and I'm not sure how to modify to do that since I didn't use a loop. Below is the code I've got so far. Any help would be greatly appreciated!! Also, this code seems like it takes a long time to run so anywhere I can clean it up to make it run smoother would be helpful as well!

```
Option Explicit

Sub test2()

Dim sh33tname As String
Dim issuetyp3 As String
Dim i As Long
Dim startrow As Long
Dim typ3 As String
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim sheetexist As Boolean
Dim sh As Worksheet

sh33tname = "Issues List"
issuetyp3 = "E"
startrow = 22

Set sh = Sheets(sh33tname)

For i = startrow To sh.Range(issuetyp3 & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).row
    typ3 = sh.Range(issuetyp3 & i).Value
    For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Sheets
        If StrComp(ws.Name, typ3, vbTextCompare) = 0 Then
            sheetexist = True
            Exit For
        End If
    Next
    If sheetexist Then
        copyrow i, sh, ws, issuetyp3
    Else
        InsertSheet type3
        Set ws = Sheets(Worksheets.Count)
        copyrow i, sh, ws, issuetyp3
    End If
    Reset sheetexist
Next i

End Sub

Private Sub copyrow(i As Long, ByRef sh As Worksheet, ByRef ws As Worksheet, issuetyp3 As String)

Dim wsrow As Long
    wsrow = ws.Range(issuetyp3 & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).row + 1
    sh.Rows(i & ":" & i).Copy
    ws.Rows(wsrow & ":" & wsrow).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False

End Sub

Private Sub Reset(ByRef x As Boolean)
    x = False
End Sub

Private Sub InsertSheet(shname As String)
    Worksheets.Add(after:=.Sheets(.Sheets.Count)).Name = shname
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should speed it up a little:

When only needing the values, skipping the clipboard and assigning the values will speed it up some.  Also, my rule of thumb is that if is only one line then a second sub or function is not needed.  I incorporated all your called subs into the code directly and moved the one I would use as a function out.

```
Sub test2()

Dim i As Long
Dim startrow As Long
Dim typ3 As String
Dim ws As Worksheet
'Dim sheetexist As Boolean
Dim sh As Worksheet

issuetyp3 = "E"
startrow = 22

Set sh = Sheets("Issues List")

For i = startrow To sh.Range(issuetyp3 & startrow).End(xldown).Row
    typ3 = sh.Range(issuetyp3 & i).Value
    If sheetexist(typ3) Then
        Set ws = Sheets(typ3)
        ws.Rows(ws.Range(issuetyp3 & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1).Value = sh.Rows(i).Value
    Else
        Set ws = Worksheets.Add(after:=Worksheets(Worksheets.Count))
        ws.Name = typ3
        ws.Rows(ws.Range(issuetyp3 & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1).Value = sh.Rows(i).Value
    End If
Next i

End Sub
Function sheetexist(nm As String) As Boolean
    sheetexist = False
    For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Sheets
        If StrComp(ws.Name, nm, vbTextCompare) = 0 Then
            sheetexist = True
            Exit For
        End If
    Next
End Function
```

Comment: I just tried this and got an "Expected Array" error on this portion: "If sheetexist(type3) Then"

Comment: Sorry forgot to get rid of the `dim sheetexist as boolean` @sfowler38

Comment: Had a couple small errors that I was able to work through by declaring variables, but now getting "Run-time error '1004': Application-defined or object-defined error" on the "Worksheets.Add(after:=.Sheets(.Sheets.Count)).Name = typ3" line

Comment: Inconsistent use of 'typ3' and 'type3'. (Always) Use 'Option Explicit' on a line before the `Sub()` to avoid this.

Comment: @user1016274 you are correct. As I did not want to build a mock workbook I did not test it.  Thanks for the catch.

Comment: That was one of the small errors that I had corrected. All instances are consistent now and I'm still getting that error.

Comment: What is the value of typ3 at when you get the error?

Comment: @sfowler38 sorry I left a test string in place of typ3.  I fixed that too.

Comment: @sfowler38 did that fix it for you?

Comment: Sorry for the delay! Updated based on the most recent version and get a "Method 'Name' of Object '_Worksheet' failed" error on the "ws.Name = typ3" line.

Comment: I do not get that error. What is the value of typ3 when it throws the error? @ sfowler38

Comment: I just stepped through it and it gives me the error when I get to a blank cell (versus stopping the loop).

Comment: @sfowler38 There must be either cells lower that are either formatted or there are values in cells after what should be the last cells.  Do this; go to the bottom of column E the very last cell on the sheet. with the last cell active hit ctrl - up arrow.  Are there blank cells above where it stops?

Comment: There is some data that is below where the last cells should be, but there are three blank rows between where the data should stop and where the additional data is. It's info that I can't delete unfortunately.

Comment: @sfowler38 I have changed to code slightly.  It will now look down for the last row not up.  Try this, but beware it will go down column E and stop at the first blank cell.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't mean for this to take as long as it is!! I tried the updated version and got the "Method 'Name' of Object '_Worksheet' failed" error. Then I tried to replace the two other areas where it says xlUp with xlDown and got the "Application-defined or object-defined error"

Comment: Can you send me a copy of the workbook? email scott.craner@gmail.com.  You should have only needed to replace your for loop line with this line `For i = startrow To sh.Range(issuetyp3 & startrow).End(xldown).Row`

Comment: @sfowler38 did you catch the fact that I replaced `.rows.count` with startrow on the for loop line?

Comment: I missed the replaced .rows.count with startrow. That did the trick!! Thank you so much Scott, I cannot thank you enough for working through this with me!! It is much appreciated!!

Comment: @sfowler38 I am glad I could help.